# How to check if content is already in the database and if it not then enter it?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've made a simple php class that extracts the daily horoscope of a astrological sign from astrology.com and i want to use it inside wordpress (using $wpdb).

Working principle (in theory):

1. check if the content is already in the database (and return it).
2. if the content it is not in the database already then add it (calling the php class i made).
3. if the class does not return the content then check if the database has an entry for the previous day and return it.
4. if none of this works return an error message

The problem is i am stuck somewhere between point 2 and 3... (i don't know how to check if the class is returning some content and if not display the one for the previous day)

```
<?php require('./wp-blog-header.php');

$horoscope = new Horoscope(); global $wpdb;

$config = array('sign' => 'cancer',
                'type' => 'daily',
                'date' => date('Y-m-d'),);

$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_horoscope` WHERE zodiacal_sign = '".$config['sign']."' AND last_updated = '".$config['date']."';", ARRAY_A);

// step 1
if( $query && $query['0']['content'] != '' ){ $content = $query['0']['content']; }

// step 2
elseif( empty($query) || $content === '' ){
$content = $horoscope->get_daily_horoscope($config);
$fetched_content = $content;
$update = $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `wp_horoscope` (`last_updated`, `content`, `zodiacal_sign`) values (%s,%s,%s)", $config['date'], $content, $config['sign']);
$wpdb->query($update);}

// step 3
elseif( $fetched_content === '' ) { // if previous function `get_daily_horoscope` does not return any content return the content for previous day
$yesterday_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('- 1 day'));
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_horoscope` WHERE zodiacal_sign = '".$config['sign']."' AND last_updated = '".$yesterday_date."';", ARRAY_A);
$content = $query['0']['content']; }

// step 4
else{$content = 'The information is not in the DB';}

echo $content;

?>
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You're always going to hit `// step 2` as content isn't initialized, and thus `elseif ( empty($query) || $content == '' )` will always return true, as the undeclared `$content` will "equal" ''.

You could try: `$content === ''` (notice extra "="), which will not be true unless it is in fact, an empty string.

Comment: Thank you, i used this with a small update based on @Martin Sheeks's answer. Could you check it please?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that you'll never get to step 3, because your case for step 3 is satisfied by step 2.

```
elseif( a || b) {

}
elseif( b ) {

}
```

you never get to elseif(b) if b is true, because b was already true in elseif(a || b).

Comment: Of course, I dunno if this will fix your overall problem, but you'll never know unless you fix your logic.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think your date calculation for yesterdays date will work. Could try this instead `date("Y-m-d", time() - 60 * 60 * 24);`

Comment: Thanks but both of them return the same date.

Comment: Later edit: if i have values both for today and yesterday the query returns me the content of this day. If i have  values for yesterday and `get_daily_horoscope` returns a string the script returns thar string (for today date). if `get_daily_horoscope` returns nothing and i have a value in the database for yesterday the script returns the error message (case 4) and adds a empty value for `content`. This is strange...